# Android: Open a PCM file in a new activity

Tags: android, file, android-activity, pcm, android-graphview

I am currently developing an app for playing PCM files and displaying their resulting line graph (thanks to jjoe64 for the [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)).

My problem now is how to open a PCM file in a new activity. Basically, the app must display the line graph for the selected file. This certain file is a list entry, so, when the user clicks the filename from the list, it will be directed to a new activity within the app for graph display.

Here is the code for the opening of a file in a list, a.k.a. the first part of my problem (from `DBActivity.java`):

```
public final static String EXTRA_FILE = "com.example.ecg_to_go.FILENAME";

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        final int sFilePosition = position;
        sFile = files[sFilePosition];
        Intent openFile = new Intent(DBActivity.this, ContentActivity.class);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sFile);
        openFile.putExtra(EXTRA_FILE, uri);
        startActivity(openFile);
    }
});
```

And here is the second part of my problem (from `ContentActivity.java`):

```
private File ecgFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
    ecgFile = new File(DBActivity.EXTRA_FILE);
    playEcg(ecgFile);   // display the PCM file
}
```

Comment: the `Uri` class implemented the interface `Parcelable`, you can add/get it from `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

Look here for how to get the extras you gave to the intent, in the started activity. You just have to call getIntent().getExtras() which returns you a bundle and the documentation is here :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Good luck :)

Comment: I have recently done that, so this is the code:
`Intent receiveFile = getIntent();
  Bundle b = receiveFile.getExtras();`
I don't know what to do after this, because I want the second activity to receive the file from the first activity. What shall I do next? Will MimeType work?

Comment: So as @chip said, you can get the Uri back from the intent :
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(DBActivity.EXTRA_FILE).
Then just open the file with the uri.

OR if you are not friendly with Parcelable, you can convert the Uri to a path (String), put it in your bundle in the first activity
openFile.putExtra(EXTRA_FILE, uri.getPath());
and then retrieve the path in the second activity by doing :
getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_FILE)
and parse it as a Uri by doing 
Uri.parse(the_path)